# How does java.lang.Object class load native fucntions?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

When I create JNI code I must use `System.load()` or `System.loadLibrary()` method to load `DLL` created in `C` or `C++` in order to use native functions.

But how do classes like `java.lang.Object` or `java.lang.System` load their own native functions like `hashCode()` or `clone()` or `setOut0(PrintStream out)`, and where does that library reside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JVM does it on behalf of `Object`, and some other classes, via the JNI function [`RegisterNatives()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#RegisterNatives).

Comment: Yes, but I still don't understand how does JVM find that function? Object calls registerNatives() native method, but that function still must be somehow linked to Object, how is that achieved without specifying path to the library, or is there some predefined location?

Comment: It doesn't need a library. See the API. You supply the address of the function directly. The function is already linked into the JVM.

Comment: That's what I was wondering about, I understand now, thank you for reply.